# CSS have image stick out from div edges

Tags: css

```
#col{
width:200px; 
float:left;
overflow:visible;
position:relative;
z-index:2;
}

<div id="col">

<img style="margin-left:-6px; z-index:999; position:relative;"  src="img.jpg" />
</div>
```

I want the image to stick out to the left by 6px but it is being cut off.

Also do I have to put 4 spaces in font of every line of code this is very slow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your image is being cutt-off, because you are using overflow on your parent `div#col`

```
<div id="col">
  <img src="img.jpg" alt="some info">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#col{
width:200px; 
float:left;
position:relative;
/*overflow: visible;*// remove
/*z-index:2;*// no need to do that
}
#col img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -6px;
width: width of image in px;
height: height of image in px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/qPhba/